# Getting black background after I merging two clipped Rasters in QGIS

Tags: qgis

So I clipped two rasters and tried to merge them but every time I merge them I'm getting a black rectangle background that I don't want. Tried clipping again with the shapefile but getting a black square background. I'm a newbie to QGIS(recently shifted from ArcGIS) and skimmed through the documentation once and don't know how to fix this. Here's some screenshot and the data I'm using:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TRnWRs4qCylupBmxNMdvkf1zlzu3QFfV?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your No Data values are getting lost in the merge. Look in the properties of the layer for the no data value. -200 in your case (not a no data value I am used to seeing)
[image: no data in properties]
Then set the no data in the output to the same. (-200)
[image: merge algo no data output]